# Embedding images from array in cells of Collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIViewController setup that also contains a UICollectionView inside of it. This Collection view has multiple cells, each of which I would like to make display an image. The images are contained in an array called `imageThumbsAray`. Each cell is a 90x90 square and I would like the image to fill the content area of each cell. Below is my code for the collection view. It seems to be correct, but when I run the app, I am returned with an empty collection view.

```
func SetupCollectionView() {
    let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 90)
    PastObjectsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 229, width: 368, height: 368), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    PastObjectsCollection!.dataSource = self
    PastObjectsCollection!.delegate = self
    PastObjectsCollection!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"Chow Object Reuse ID")

}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectsCount
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Chow Object Reuse ID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90)
    imageView.image = imageThumbsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.addSubview(imageView)
    return cell
}
```

Why is the Collection view not creating the cells?

Thanks,
Siddharth

Comment: You never added your collection view to your view.

Comment: I have a collection view created in Interface Builder, and wired to the code as an IBOutlet (PastObjectsCollection). Do I need to explicitly still add it to the view?

Comment: No, but then why are you creating one in the SetupCollectionView() function? Do you also have a cell in the collection view you made in IB?

Comment: I'm trying to modify the properties of the Collection View in code, hence the method `SetupCollectionView()`. There is one cell in the collection view in IB. However, the number of cells is contingent upon the number of items in the `imageThumbsArray`, which is not predetermined

Comment: Well, that code is wrong. You need to reference the collection view you made in IB through its IBOutlet, not create a new one.

Comment: yes, removing the `SetupCollectionView()` method did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code use as much of your code as as I could.  You can compare line by line.  I did't have your image assets or object array.  This is all programmatic.  Let me know if you need more help.

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var PastObjectsCollection:UICollectionView?
    var layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        SetupCollectionView()
    }


    func SetupCollectionView() {
        self.layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        self.layout!.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        self.layout!.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 90)
        self.PastObjectsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 229, width: 368, height: 368), collectionViewLayout: layout!)
        self.PastObjectsCollection!.dataSource = self
        self.PastObjectsCollection!.delegate = self
        self.PastObjectsCollection!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"Chow Object Reuse ID")
        self.PastObjectsCollection!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.view.addSubview(self.PastObjectsCollection!)

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 //objectsCount
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Chow Object Reuse ID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90)
        //imageView.image = imageThumbsArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.addSubview(imageView)
        return cell
    }
}
```